# write with php code in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var id=<?php print''.entry1->id.''?>;
 var dataString = 'id='+ id;

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax_unfollow.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
 });         

</script>
```

there have a error in this line

```
var id=<?php print''.entry1->id.''?>;
```

how can i write php code in var id?

this javascript run in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 3):

write like this :

```
var id= '<?php echo entry1->id;?>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var id = '<?=$entry1->id?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a single quotes around your PHP expression.

So, the corrected code should be:

```
var id='<?php print''.entry1->id.''?>';
```

Also, another thing:

You should avoid [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

So, please use `<?php echo $variable;?>` instead of `<?=$variable;?>`.

Because, most of the PHP running servers should have [short_open_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) directive off.

So, your PHP code, in this case will be considered as a plain text and will be shown to user.

Without it, whatever generated by the PHP should be considered as a JavaScript variable.

Which should cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

since value of print should be string so you can try this code.

```
var id="<?php print''.entry1->id.''?>";
```